# Rails query optimization, doing it the wrong way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a Team and a Tag model, linked through a simple TeamTag model with foreign keys (tag_id, team_id).
I'm trying to get all the tags from specific teams with a specific tag_type, with one query.
Here's what I'm at right now :

```
TeamTag.joins(:tag, :team).where(tags: {tag_type: 1}, teams: {id: [1,2]}).map(&:tag)
```

Is there a way to start with Tag.joins... instead so I can avoid the .map() at the end that does an extra query ?

When I'm trying the other way I get a join error :

```
Tag.joins(:teams, :team_tags).where(tag_type:0, teams: {id: u.teams})
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Tag' to association named 'teams'; perhaps you misspelled it?)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get "*Can't join 'Tag' to association named 'teams'*" is because `tag` isn't directly related to `teams`, but it has another table in between (`team_tags`).

`joins` allows you to refer to such relationships as:

```
Tag.joins(team_tags: :team)
```

Comma-separated values mean they're directly related to the table/model you're invoking `joins` in.

You could start from Tag, but using the relationship between tag -> team_tags -> team:

```
Tag.joins(team_tags: :team).where(teams: { tag_type: 1, id: [1, 2] })
```